# Computing light scattering to remove it from a signal

Tags: visible-light

Suppose that I am outdoors in a city on a sunny day.

I have 2 objects A and B, identical white light diffusors, and a very precise spectrophotometer.

A is 1 meter away from my spectrophotometer, B is 5000 meters away.

[image: One curve made by the spectrophotometer, resolution 1 nm]

I get two spectral curves Ca and Cb with my spectrophotometer, which I normalize (dividing all values by the highest one).

- I find that Cb has **smaller** values in the short wavelengths (300 to 400 nm), which I suppose is due to Rayleigh scattering
- there may be some other differences not due to scattering, e.g. to light absorbance by some particles in the air

Suppose that I want to get the spectral absorbance of the air particles that are floating in the atmosphere, what mathematical model would you use to compute an image of the effect of Rayleigh scattering in order remove it from the data and observe the absorbance of the particules ?

Comment: It seems to me that Cb should be redder than Ca. Right? Then, without promising, I will think about...

Comment: I mean what you get from scattering right along the path cannot exceed what is scattered away......

Comment: Oh I am sorry you're right

Comment: Basically your question is to distinguish what is absorbed by 5 km atmosphere and what is scattered. If it is so, better you search for Rayleigh scattering cross section. You could obtain what you are looking for by integrating. Of course you need to know the density of atmosphere at the given T and P. Moreover, in your question, you cannot treat a and b as the same source, io have to correct for the solid angle. In other words you ideate a rather complicated experiment. Even if you could make vacuum between b and the spectrophotometer, the problem of isolating scattering and true absorptionv

Comment: ..... remains . However not polluted atmosphere is transparent if electronic absorption. I am just afraid of resonance by water vapours but I do not think is real for just 5 km gas

Comment: @Alchimista yes you have defined perfectly what I wanna do. You are right about the solid angle, but isn't it possible to simply use inverse-square law to estimate the difference in intensity between Ca and Cb? My spectrophotometer is mounted on a strong telefocus and I know its transmission curve in UV, VIS and near IR. It has a field of view of exactly 2°.

Comment: @Alchimista I mean supposing that the illuminance at A and B are the same... on a clear day, at two spots that have an equal amount of particles in their atmosphere...

Comment: Yes I think it comes to focus and then use the inverse squared law. But still I do not see how to distinguish what is absorbed from what is scattered until you do not get documentation on the Rayleigh intensities. I would assume atmosphere to be fully transparent, so that any difference (after correction for distance) between spectra A and B is just scattering (of any type). But this is in contradiction with what you want to measure...

Comment: Unless you want to get a kind of average data on pollution/pollen whatever particulate. Than it make sense. More droplets and or particulate will result in less light to your spectrophotometer. But I will call that scattering not absorption, and such measurements cannot distinguish between industrial dust and pollen, for instance. Back to your original question as formulated, you should really search for a pure Rayleigh diff spectrum that account for actual intensity and scale it to 5 km optical thickness.... Let me know

Comment: You could create a monte carlo simulation for this, using what you know of Rayleigh scattering as far as angles and probability for different energy levels are concern and then create a graph of the intensities reaching you. This would require you getting information, like atmospheric composition, and checking this against your current results first. It is the best way I can think of for creating a simulated model to subtract from your data.